# is it possible to display my interactive igraph tree in an python tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tree, igraph

i have made an interactive tree using igraph, I can see my tree in my webbrowser. but now I want my tree to show inside an gui window. is this possible?

### this is my code:

I tried a couple libraries that turn my tree into an html file and then I could open this into an tkinter window. however did didn't work for me.

```
class Tree():
    def __init__(self, experimentPF, celltypePF, genetypePF, timepointPF,
                 conditionsPF, technical_repPF, analytical_repPF):

        # Create an empty graph
        g = igraph.Graph(directed=True)

        # Add top node expirement name
        for exp in experimentPF:
            g.add_vertex(exp)

        # add FA node
        for celltype in celltypePF:
            fa_node = f"{exp}_{celltype}"
            g.add_vertex(fa_node)
            g.add_edge(exp, fa_node)

        # add exp node
        for genetype in genetypePF:
            exp_node = f"{exp}_{celltype}_{genetype}"
            g.add_vertex(exp_node)
            g.add_edge(fa_node, exp_node)

        # add TX node
        for timepoint in timepointPF:
            tx_node = f"{exp}_{celltype}_{genetype}_{timepoint}"
            g.add_vertex(tx_node)
            g.add_edge(exp_node, tx_node)

        # Add C nodes
        for condition in conditionsPF:
            c_nodes = f"{exp}_{celltype}_{genetype}_{timepoint}_{condition}"
            g.add_vertex(c_nodes)
            g.add_edge(tx_node, c_nodes)

            # Add TR nodes
            for tech_rep in technical_repPF:  # TR1, TR2, TR3
                tr_node = f"{exp}_{celltype}_{genetype}_{timepoint}_{condition}_{tech_rep}"
                g.add_vertex(tr_node)
                g.add_edge(c_nodes, tr_node)

                # Add 5 AR nodes for each TR node
                for analy_rep in analytical_repPF:  # AR1, AR2, AR3, AR4, AR5
                    ar_node = f"{exp}_{celltype}_{genetype}_{timepoint}_{condition}_{tech_rep}_{analy_rep}"
                    g.add_vertex(ar_node)
                    g.add_edge(tr_node, ar_node)

        # Convert igraph layout to Plotly format
        layt = g.layout("rt")


        # Get edge coordinates
        edge_x, edge_y = [], []
        for edge in g.get_edgelist():
            x0, y0 = layt[edge[0]]
            x1, y1 = layt[edge[1]]
            edge_x.extend([x0, x1, None])
            edge_y.extend([y0, y1, None])

        # Get vertex coordinates and labels
        node_x, node_y = zip(*[layt[vertex] for vertex in g.vs.indices])
        # node_labels = [str(label) for label in g.vs.indices]
        node_labels = g.vs['name']

        # Create Plotly trace for edges
        edge_trace = go.Scatter(
            x=edge_x,
            y=edge_y,
            line=dict(width=0.5, color="#888"),
            hoverinfo="none",
            mode="lines",
        )

        # Create Plotly trace for nodes
        node_trace = go.Scatter(
            x=node_x,
            y=node_y,
            mode="markers",
            hoverinfo="text",
            marker=dict(size=10),
            text=node_labels,  # Display node labels on hover
        )

        # Create a figure and add traces
        fig = go.Figure(data=[edge_trace, node_trace])

        # Customize layout
        fig.update_layout(
            showlegend=True,
            hovermode="closest",
            margin=dict(b=0, l=0, r=0, t=0),
            xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False),
            yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False, autorange='reversed'),
        )


        # g.write_dot('mijn boom')

        g.plot(g, "name.png")
        # Show the interactive plot
        fig.show()
```